# What is a telemetry configuration and Why we use it in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-application-insights

I am new in ASP.NET Core 1. I see such code section in `_Layout.cshtml`.

```
@Html.ApplicationInsightsJavaScript(TelemetryConfiguration)
```

And I can not understand what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you add TelemetryConfiguration in your application, you can sends telemetry data from the server (back end) of your application. Using this you can add client-side monitoring. This provides you with data on users, sessions, page views, and any exceptions or crashes that occur in the browser.

To enable Application Insights, you need to add `“Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore”` to the project.json file

```
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
```

In the method ConfigureServices add Application Insights service like this-

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

In _ViewImports.cshtml, add injection like this-

```
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration TelemetryConfiguration
```

Any custom javascript telemetry you want to report from the page should be injected after this snippet.

```
@Html.ApplicationInsightsJavaScript(TelemetryConfiguration)
```

Complete details explained in this [post](http://dotnetthoughts.net/using-application-insights-in-aspnet-core/)